# Webpack bundle - Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, ecmascript-6

I am trying to achieve the following:

- `bundle` (**in this order**) `jquery`, `tether`, and `bootstrap.js`.
- load this bundle within a `HTML`page and beneath it load other page specific scripts.

To achieve this I am using `webpack 2` and the `CommonsChunkPlugin`. Here is my config.

For `entries` I have:

```
const scriptsEntry = {
    blog_index: SRC_DIR + "/js/pages/blog_index.js",
    blog_about: SRC_DIR + "/js/pages/blog_about.js",
    vendor: ["jquery", "tether", "bootstrap"]
};
```

In the `plugins` section:

```
scriptsPlugins.push(
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: "vendor", 
        filename:"vendor.bundle.js", 
        minChunks: 2
    }),
    ...
}));
```

Inside 'index.html' I load the bundles:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='dist/js/vendor.bundle.js') + anti_cache_token }}"></script>
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='dist/js/home.js') + anti_cache_token }}"></script>
```

Inside the source directory in the `blog_index.js` I make use of `jquery`:

```
import $ from "jquery";

$(".home-click").click(function () {
    alert("clicked from .home-click");
});
```

**The result:**

- everything bundles without any errors.
- when I click `.home-click` the `alert box` fires as expected.
- checking the bundled files I see that:

  - `vendor.bundle.js` contains: `jquery`, `tether`, and `bootstrap`.
  - looking inside, for instance, `blog_index.js` (after it was run through `webpack 2`), I notice that the `jquery` import is not bundled inside this file, but `vendor.bundle.js` (this is as expected).

However, I have the following **problem** when I check the browser console:
[image]

I tried switching the order of the libraries in this line `vendor: ["jquery", "tether", "bootstrap"]`, but nothing changed--the error is still there.

Do you know how can I solve this, preferably without using additional `webpack` plugins?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Bootstrap's javascript assumes that jQuery is hooked on the `window` object, it does not require it or anything.

By bundling stuff up, you do not expose variables to the global scope, or at least you should not be doing that. So the bootstrap code cannot find jQuery.

Add this to your plugins and you should be ok

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    tether: 'tether',
    Tether: 'tether',
    'window.Tether': 'tether',
})
```

This will replace all instances where `jQuery` is assumed as global with the export of the jQuery package, which is the `jQuery` object. Same for `Tether`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have a short question: does adding this have an effect on the `vendor.bundle.js`?

Comment: Yes, it will be replacing instances of the word `jQuery`, `$`, `window.jQuery` etc, with something that actually points to the `jQuery` object. For example, something like this `* WEBPACK VAR INJECTION */(function(jQuery, __webpack_provided_window_dot_Tether, Tether) {/*!`. It does not affect functionality in any way,

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand, but just to make sure: because it only exposes the plugin it means that I don't have to modify the configuration of `entry` and `CommonChunksPlugin`. Did I get it correctly?

Comment: You definitely don't need to modify your `entry` or anything in the `CommonChunksPlugin`, but I don't understand what is that confuses you. What do you mean by 'only exposes the plugin' ? Help me help you

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My concern was that I would end up bundling the libraries twice (`ProvidePlugin` and `CommonChunksPlugin`). However, reading your explanations I understand that only modules that are already loaded inside `vendor.bundle.js` will be exposed using the `ProvidePlugin` if specified so. Is this a little more clear?

Comment: I also marked it as accepted answer - it works. I just wanted to understand what's happening behind the scenes to avoid duplicated things inside the bundles.

Comment: Ok. Using more than one plugins does not mean you are bundling things twice, or thrice or whatever. You are bundling once, but the end result, the output, gets affected by all the used plugins. Using the `ProvidePlugin` will not affect only the `vendor.bundle.js`. It just happens here, in this case, that only the Bootstrap code has instances where the `ProvidePlugin` can be applied on. If, in your own code, you were trying to use `jQuery` from the global scope, `ProvidePlugin` would be applied there as well.

Comment: This last comment clears away the confusion. It's actually useful to access i.e., `jquery` without having to import it in every file it's needed. Thanks for taking your time to explain all this! I very much appreciate it!

Comment: "It's actually useful to access i.e., jquery without having to import it in every file it's needed" Well, it's actually a good practice to be importing dependencies in packages that need them, instead of assuming that they will be somehow available, by means of webpack magic.

Comment: Took note of this! Thanks again!

Comment: Many thanks! I've noticed that this error blocked for me auto update in visual studio code after saving e.g. sass files. After adding this to plugins, my errors gone :)