# can't include bootstrap in react-app project because bootstrap js can't find jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, webpack

I want to access bootstrap classes in my react app.

So at the top of App.js I put :

```
import 'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
```

But when I run the app I get

> Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
>       ▼ 13 stack frames were expanded.
>       ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
>       node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js:6
>       **webpack_require**
>       /Users/levkowalski/Dropbox/Dev Work/react/game/webpack/bootstrap 4a4600e4aeb932c83f04:669
>       fn
>       /Users/levkowalski/Dropbox/Dev Work/react/game/webpack/bootstrap 4a4600e4aeb932c83f04:87
>       ./src/App.js
>       http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41844:93

Why is that happening since I loaded jQuery globaly just before ?

Comment: Use react-strap specially made for react applications. Some people say it is not a good idea to use jquery with react js because react js has its own virtual DOM.

Comment: Remeber react-strap is made with bootstrap 4 idk about bootstrap 3.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41778884/webpack-bundle-bootstraps-javascript-requires-jquery Hope this helps!