# Bootstrap requires Jquery after bundling with webpack

Tags: angularjs, webpack

`main.js`

```
let jquery = require("../Scripts/jquery-2.2.4.js");
let bootstrap = require("../Scripts/bootstrap.js");
let angular = require("../Scripts/angular.js");
let ngRoute = require("../Scripts/angular-route.js");
let messages = require("../Scripts/angular-messages.js");

let appmodule = require("../app.module.js");
let appconfig = requre("../ap.config.js");

let service = require("../service.js");

let homemodule = require("../home-view/home-view.module.js");
let homecomponent = requre("../home-view/home-view.component.js");

let editmodule = require("../edit-view/edit-view.module.js");
let editcomponent = requre("../edit-view/edit-view.component.js");

let addmodule = require("../add-view/add-view.module.js");
let addcomponent = requre("../add-view/add-view.component.js");
```

`webpack config`

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

    entry: "./main.js", //relative to root of the application
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "../app.bundle.js" //relative to root of the application
    },
    watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 300,
        poll: 1000
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            hash: true,
            title: 'My Interviewe Evaluation',
            myPageHeader: 'interviewee',
            template: '../_index.html',
            filename: '../index.html' //relative to root of the application
        })
    ]
}
```

After running the app it gives this Error: Bootstrap requires jQuery. How do I solve this? Before I use webpack, the project was working as intended.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41778884/webpack-bundle-bootstraps-javascript-requires-jquery

Comment: That does not solve my problem unfortunately :/